# a subset of $l_2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

the exercise is: show that the set $A=\{x=(x_n)\subset l_2: \sum(1+\frac{1}{i})x_i^2)\leq 1\}$ doesn't contain an element with norm equal to $\sup\{\|x\|_2,x\in A\}$.

My attempt: i showed that $\forall x\in A, \|x\|_2^2=\sum x_i^2< \sum x_i^2+\frac{x_i^2}{i}\leq 1$. And $\sup_{x\in A} \|x\|=1$. Using that $l_2$ is a Hilbert space, is there a way to show that, supposing that exists an element that there is norm equal to $\sup\{\|x\|_2,x\in A\}$, find some contradiction?  This exercise i found at functional analysis and infinite-dimensional geometry- Marián Fabian.

Comment: $(i+\frac 1i)x^2_i \gt 2x^2_i \gt x^2_i$  for $i\ge 2$ ?

Comment: My idea would be to define $ A_i $ to be the subset of $ A $ with all terms vanishing after the ith position.  Then find the maximal norm element $ x_i^* $.  Then the limit of their norms will be the supremal norm of elements of $ A $, but then you can show that $ x_i^* $ doesn't converge in $ l_2 $.

Comment: In the definition of $A$, I think it should be $1 + \frac{1}{i}$ instead of $i + \frac{1}{i}$. As written, $(1/\sqrt{2}, 0, 0, \dotsc)$ is an element of maximal norm in $A$.

Comment: its 1... edited!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $x\in A$. Since for all $i\ge 1$ we have $x_i^2\le (i+1/i)x_i^2$ we conclude by adding these inequalities that $\Vert x\Vert_2^2\le 1$, so
$$\sup_{x\in A}\Vert x\Vert_2\le 1.$$
Now, if we define $x^{(k)}\in\ell_2$ by $x^{(k)}_k=1/\sqrt{1+1/k}$ and  $x^{(k)}_i=0$ for $i\ne k$, then $x^{(k)}\in A$ and
$$\Vert x^{(k)}\Vert_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/k}}\le \sup_{x\in A}\Vert x\Vert_2\le 1$$
But since $k$ is arbitrary we conclude by letting $k$ tend to $\infty$ that
$$ \sup_{x\in A}\Vert x\Vert_2=1.$$

Now, suppose that there exists $y\in A$ such that $\Vert y\Vert_2=1$ then
$$\sum_{i\ge1}\frac1i y_i^2=
\sum_{i\ge1}\left(1+\frac1i \right)y_i^2
-\sum_{i\ge1}y_i^2\le1-\Vert y\Vert_2^2=0$$
Thus
$$\sum_{i\ge1}\frac1i y_i^2=0$$
So $y_i=0$ for all $i$ and this contradicts the fact that $\Vert y\Vert_2=1$. This contradiction proves that there is no $y\in A$ such that $\Vert y\Vert_2=1$. $\qquad\square$

Comment: yes... i agreed... i thought that was possible to do something with hilbert space... something like write with inner product. Thanks!